# C#/WinForm - TreeView Nodes: Add to variable and compare

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, nodes

To make it easier for you guys to understand what I'm asking, I'm going to write a full process:

**1) App starts**

**2) Button1 is pressed:**

-populate TreeView1 with news article titles

-add first node to variable 1

**3) Button1 is pressed:**

-populate TreeView1 with new article titles

-add first node to variable 2

-compare variable 1 and 2, if they are different show a message box. If they are the same do nothing.

**4) Button1 is pressed:**

-populate TreeView1 with new article titles

-add first node to variable 3

-compare variable 2 and 3, if they are different show a message box. If they are the same do nothing.

And so on and on....

Basically every time button1 is pressed, first node is stored into new variable and compared to previous variable.

**So my question is: How can I store 'First Node' to a different variable every time the button1 is pressed?**

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: What are you wanting to compare? Just the text of the article titles?

Comment: Only article titles are stored in the TreeView. But comparing isn't the issue I know the code for that, the issue is storing the 'First node' to a different variable every time button1 is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the TreeNode.Tag property as that's what it's there for. As you populate the TreeView with nodes, set the Tag property of each node to something that uniquely identifies the news article associated with it. I generally set it to the object the Node is trying to represent, in this case a news article.

```
private void LoadNewsArticles()
{
    List<MyNewsArticle> newsArticles = GetNewsArticles();

    foreach(MyNewsArticle a in newsArticles)
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(a.Title)
        node.Tag = a;
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
    }
}
```

Then, when you need to compare Node values, you can just look at the Tags.

```
private MyNewsArticle _currentTopArticle;

private void button1_Click(object sender EventArgs e)
{
    LoadNewsArticles();

    TreeNode topNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
    MyNewsArticle topArticle = topNode.Tag as MyNewsArticle;
    if(topArticle.Equals(_currentTopArticle))
    {
        // Do something
    }

    _currentTopArticle = topArticle;
}
```

Note that this example is only keeping track of the previous one top article because your problem doesn't indicate a need for more than that. If you do indeed need to maintain a full history of top articles, you'll want to have a list of articles and simply keep pushing the latest top story onto it every time you load.

Comment: What's "GetNewsArticles()"?

Comment: @FicVic It's just an arbitrary function that will get the data to put into the TreeView. The data itself isn't important for this answer - the goal was to demonstrate how to attach an object to a TreeNode using the Tag property.

Answer (score 0):

Before clearing out the existing nodes. Push the first node into a list as shown below.

```
private List<TreeNode> previousNodes;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    previousNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    previousNodes.Add(treeView1.Nodes[0]);
    //Clear out nodes, add new ones
    //Compare by treeView1.Nodes[0].Text == previousNodes.Last().Text
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. When I compare the nodes in treeview and on the list, the result will always be true, even if the text of treeview node and last node on the list isn't same. So basically I'll always get the same result.